# How can I get an ICollection property out of a IRecord?

Tags: c#, record, enumerator

I have an IRecord which contains an ICollection of Samples. The ICollection looks like this:

```
Sample sample1 = scope.DbContext.Samples.AddNew(new Sample 
        { 
            Name = GenerateName("Sample one"),
            Tests = tests
        });

Sample sample2 = scope.DbContext.Samples.AddNew(new Sample 
    { 
        Name = GenerateName("Sample two"),
        Tests = tests
    });

ICollection<Sample> samples = new Collection<Sample>();
samples.Add(sample1);
samples.Add(sample2);
```

Then I add the samples to the record:

```
Order record = scope.DbContext.Orders.AddNew(new Order 
{ 
    Name = GenerateName("Order"),
    Samples = samples 
});
```

Now I want to get the Samples out of the record. I know that when I do

```
object name = record["Name"];
```

I get the correctly generated name. However, when I do

```
object propertyValue = record["Samples"];
```

it has no items in it. I want to do the following:

```
object propertyValue = record["Samples"];
if (typeof(IEnumerable<IRecord>).IsAssignableFrom(propertyValue.GetType()))
{
    foreach (var property in (IEnumerable<IRecord>)propertyValue)
    {
        var test = property;
    }
}
```

So why does record["Samples"] not get the ICollection?

Comment: What do you get with record["Samples"]?

Comment: Could you show us the code for `IRecord`?

Comment: @Adriano I get {System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<iVention.Database.Sample>}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me, that what you really want to use is the `as` keyword.

```
var samples = record["Samples"] as ICollection<Sample>;
```

However, why aren't you just using the CLR static type?

```
var samples = record.Samples;
```

Maybe I am just not understanding what you are trying to do here, but it seems like it can be boiled pretty simply to the above.

Comment: I don't know beforehand what type the ICollection holds. I'm trying to do it this way to get around the ICollection<Sample> method.

Comment: @NiekdeKlein Do all the possible types inherit from one base class/interface? You could always try generics if not.

Comment: var samples = record["Samples"] as ICollection<Sample>; gives same result as var property in (IEnumerable<IRecord>)propertyValue, it's also empty